# Centering fixed width layout while keeping a minimum width scrollable

Tags: html, css, center

I am working on a graphically intense layout, so to keep file size down I am limiting the layout to a 1600 pixel fixed width.

Of the 1600 pixels, the important content falls within the center 1230.

I am trying to find a way to center the layout in the browser while keeping the content scrollable.

This solution does not center when the browser window is less than 1600px

```
#page{margin: 0 auto;}
```

This solution makes left hand side of content unreachable as the browser width gets smaller.

```
#page{position: absolute; width: 1600px; top: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -800px; }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution solves the inaccessible content issues.

If you have the following structure

```
#wrap.constrained > #layout > #content.constrained
```

You can use the constrained class to limit both #wrap and #content to the desired width and center both horizontally by setting side margins to "auto".

You could then position #layout absolutely, have it be bigger than .constrained, and use a combination of left positioning and negative left margin to center it in regards to #wrap.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/caKA7/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center an element in a wrapper that is smaller than the element and you can use `absolute`:

```
    #page{
      position: absolute;
      width: 1600px;
      top: 0;
      left:-100%;
      right:-100%;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
   }
```

example:http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/T5d8W/

Comment: Just so you know, this breaks if the size of the inner element is larger than the defined size of the outer one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, in the example the size of the inner element is larger than the defined size of the outer one and it seems to work fine, unless I didn't understand something.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain fully. It breaks once the width exceeds the 100% off the side of the parent, that is, in your sample once the inner width is larger than 150 px.

Comment: @nit You are very very right! I had never noticed that! Actually, it is the width + left + right which in this example is 300% which is 150px. Using bigger percentages will fix that of course, but still, it isn't a very elegant solution. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need to limit width in pixels. It isn't very portable across devices, and it's not clear why you're doing it. However, if you want to center a 1230px region within 1600px, you can just use fixed-width margins of size `(1600-1230) / 2`.

For more flexible solutions, are flex-boxes an acceptable technology? If so, they make this task trivial. Make page container with:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
```

Then make your items

```
  flex: 0 0 auto
```

or set a specific width instead of `auto`.

Comment: Solutions that have wider support would be better in my opinion, see http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: Six months ago I'd have agreed, but at this point flex boxes are supported by all major browsers, and have been for two versions.